# JSX element type 'App' is not a constructor function for JSX elements. Types of property 'setState' are incompatible

Tags: reactjs, typescript2.0

I am using the [Microsoft TypeScript-React-Starter](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter) and got this compile error during `npm start`:

```
./src/index.tsx
(16,5): error TS2605: JSX element type 'App' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
  Types of property 'setState' are incompatible.
    Type '{ <K extends never>(f: (prevState: null, props: {}) => Pick<null, K>, callback?: (() => any) | un...' is not assignable to type '{ <K extends never>(f: (prevState: {}, props: any) => Pick<{}, K>, callback?: (() => any) | undef...'.
      Types of parameters 'f' and 'f' are incompatible.
        Type '(prevState: {}, props: any) => Pick<{}, any>' is not assignable to type '(prevState: null, props: {}) => Pick<null, any>'.
          Types of parameters 'prevState' and 'prevState' are incompatible.
            Type 'null' is not assignable to type '{}'.
```

So it seems like my `setState` function has incorrect signature but I'm not sure how to fix it. Here's my code:

```
class App extends React.Component<{}, null> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        ...
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
```

I am using:

```
node v6.11.0
npm v5.1.0
typescript v2.4.1
react v15.6.1
redux v3.7.1
react-redux v5.0.5
react-scripts-ts v2.3.2
```

**Update:**

I found out that removing the generic types `<{}, null>` clears the error. But I'd still love to learn why I was getting the error.

Comment: If App component does not use state, you can actually make it a functional stateless component instead.

Comment: @D-reaper `App` does use state in my case. I'm using `redux` to manage the state. I guess that's why I don't have to explicitly write `prevState()`?

Comment: I think since you are passing `null` as the second type argument in React.Component, which defines the structure of state and that it is only compatible with certain types (e.g object) thus causing TS to throw that error. `<any, any>` or just `<{}>` would also work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

TLDR; State cannot be null. Declare a interface for it or declare it `{}`

Answer lies in [@types/react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react)

Looking at the [definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L237), neither state nor props are not intended to be null.

When you declared `App` as `class App extends React.Component<{}, null> {`, you essentially said, "state is of type null".

Now the type of `setState` is dependent on the type you specify for state and it clashed with the [lesser known version of the setState api](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). `prevState` is declared as a {} (the default, since no interface for state was specified) which is not compatible with null, leading to the error log you saw.

Comment: Since [this PR](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/17288) was merged, omitting the type parameters will cause the component to be created using the prop and state defaults (`{}`, `{}`). Assumes TS > 2.3.

Comment: Just a note that we got this using `void` as well.  Removing the state argument entirely and just using the property argument makes the compiler happy again.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this fix isn't relevant but I got the same error message without having `<{}, null>` after `class App extends React.Component`. Here is the fix in my case.

Change `import React from 'react';`

to `import * as React from 'react';`

Comment: This is a completely different issue, and depends on how you've configured `allowSyntheticDefaultImports`

Comment: @PaulGray this is in fact exactly the problem I had. The imported file wasn't importing React correctly so it wasn't seen as a React component by TS.

Comment: But it's still a completely different issue :D