# JSX element type 'App' is not a constructor function for JSX elements. Type 'App' is missing the following properties from type 'ElementClass'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, frontend

I'm new to typescript so I'm just simply trying to get this to build. Please ignore my use of 'any' at the moment. Anyway I'm not really sure what the error means

Error in question: JSX element type 'App' is not a constructor function for JSX elements. Type 'App' is missing the following properties from type 'ElementClass' context, setState, forceUpdate, props, and 2 more.

... and I'm still confused after googling it.

I've tried deleting and re-installing package-lock.json and yarn.lock files to see if there were any inconsistencies between them but it didn't seem to fix the problem.

App.tsx:

```
class App extends React.Component<any, any> {

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {

        }
    }

    render() {
        const { brand, links } = navigation;
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Navbar brand={brand} links={links} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const navigation = {
    brand: { name: "Navbar", to: "/" },
    links: [
        { name: "About us", to: "/about" },
        { name: "Transactions", to: "/transactions" },
        { name: "Contact", to: "/contact" },
  ]
}

export default App;
```

index.tsx, where the error occurs in App

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Any thoughts on what might be causing this error?

Comment: `<any, any>` is strange. I never saw this

Comment: My bad. It's supposed to be <any, {}>. It doesn't affect the error though,

Comment: If you remove the `<any, any>` is the error gone?

Comment: No, it's still there unfortunately. Could you tell me what this error means ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45024559/jsx-element-type-app-is-not-a-constructor-function-for-jsx-elements-types-of